# Writing something at top before fixed navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to write the website name and slogan at the top before the fixed navbar.I have this fixed navbar but whereever i write the website title and slogan the navbar remains at the top.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My top 5 music</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="nirvana.php">Nirvana</a></li>
            <li><a href="gnr.php">Guns N'Roses</a></li> 
            <li><a href="beatles.php">The beatles</a></li> 
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="register.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

I am trying exactly like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

Comment: Do you have CSS? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the effect in your example link you could initially set the header to have a position: relative in the css, and then add then change it to position:fixed once the user has scrolled past a certain point on the screen e.g.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="site-name">Site name</div>
<div class="nav-bar">Nav bar</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav-bar {
    position: relative;
}
.nav-bar.open {
    position: fixed;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var scrollingNav = function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 50) { 
        $('.nav-bar').addClass('open');
    }
    else {
        $('.nav-bar').removeClass('open');
    }
};

$(window).scroll(function () {
    scrollingNav();
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/s5pwu3cj/1/

Answer (score 1):

Just simply add of course a division at the top of your nav.
So you can basically do something like this.

HTML:

```
<div id="slogan">Slogan here</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My top 5 music</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="nirvana.php">Nirvana</a></li>
            <li><a href="gnr.php">Guns N'Roses</a></li> 
            <li><a href="beatles.php">The beatles</a></li> 
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="register.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
  top: 20px;
  }

  #slogan {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  }
```

The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/claudios/b77ck3Lx/)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qetea973/)

I've just added another `navbar` above the original and moved the original one down

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h3>Logo</h3>
    </div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-nav">
  ...
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-nav {
    top: 50px;
}
```